# How to find which TVs are currently using my app?

Tags: google-analytics, android-tv, leanback

I am developing an app for Android TV is it possible to know, on which TV my app is running or what action is performed on it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To review your app's supported devices:

1. Sign in to your [Play Console](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/).
2. Select an app.
3. On the left menu, click
   Release management > Device catalog. If you haven't already, review
   and accept the Terms of Service.
4. Select the All, Supported, or
   Excluded tabs. If you want to download a list of devices as a CSV
   file, near the right side of the page, click Download device list.

For more infos:
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7353455

To track action performed on your app, you can use Fabric's Answers plug in.
Here is a sample code you'll need to add in your code to track events in Answers:

```
public void onKeyMetric() {
    // TODO: Use your own string attributes to track common values over time
    // TODO: Use your own number attributes to track median value over time
    Answers.getInstance().logCustom(new CustomEvent("Video Played")
            .putCustomAttribute("Category", "Comedy")
            .putCustomAttribute("Length", 350));
}
```

For more infos:
https://fabric.io/kits/android/answers

Comment: Sorry @matdev I haven't pay the Regestration fee yet can you please tell me that 
in console we have all about on which tv app is live now ?

Comment: Yes you can, if you have access to the Play Console

Comment: one thing more i want to know that i have some videos in my app so i have to upscale all video according to TV screen resolution ?

Comment: This is a different topic. Please accept my answer and post an other question